# a rite of passage

Tags: phrase-meaning

Does "a rite of passage" mean "a symbolic ceremony"?

Found in:

> For many South Korean adoptees, returning to their birth country has become **a rite of passage** — canceled indefinitely by the pandemic. But some have persisted, making flights and staying in quarantine to meet their biological families for the first time.

Source: The NYTimes just tweeted

Comment: A "rite" means a "symbolic ceremony" (roughly). "Passage" is the thing it's celebrating.

Comment: *"Does "a rite of passage" mean "a symbolic ceremony"?* Yes it does. I believe the origin of this to be nautical, referring to the rituals undergone when crossing the equator during an ocean passage (journey). https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/behind-the-strange-and-controversial-ritual-when-you-cross-the-equator-at-sea

Comment: This is easy to Google. Did you try looking up a definition?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a *rite of passage* is a ceremony marking a person's transition into a new phase of life (a tribal initiation, confirmation or bar mitzvah, university graduation). Here, it's being used more loosely to mean 'something that people in that situation feel they have to do when they grow up'.

Comment: The word for how it's being used here is "figuratively" or "metaphorically".

Comment: “Your first hangover is a rite of passage.” is an example of usage that is valid but  as far from a formal ceremony as can be imagined.